# Prevent Exit On All Click Events With Google Swiffy

Tags: google-swiffy, double-click-advertising

We have a 300x250 banner with 3 click events.

First click event will activate a lever. 
Second click event is a CTA (i.e. exit event) that takes the user to a URL. 
Third click event is the replay icon.

The issue is that every click will take the user to the URL (i.e. exit event).

How can I separate each click event? Is it done within Flash? Or after the Swiffy conversion (i.e. within the HTML/JS)?

Does this have anything to do with bubbling? Or is it that the exit event is somehow being tied to every click?

I thought about having the clicks timed but that screws up the whole experience.

I've tried `stopPropigation` but it prevents the add from working. Also, I don't want the first click to be stopped. It still needs to work accordingly.

HTML

```
<div id="bg-exit">
   <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 300px; height: 250px">
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</div>
```

JS

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {  });

      stage.start();   

        function bgExitHandler(e) {
          Enabler.exit('Background Exit');

        } 

    document.getElementById('bg-exit').addEventListener('click', bgExitHandler, false);
```